# Angular Material Toolbar Color Distorted

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

#### A Code pen that illustrates this problem can be found at http://cdpn.io/VKxEaZ

I have been experiencing an issue with Angular Material in regards to the toolbar having distorted colors. Along the edges (where there is content) the toolbar is one shade of green while in the middle (where there is no content) the toolbar is a different shade of green. See the picture below:

[image: Toolbar that is miscolored]

The code that produced this is as below.

```
<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h2><span>Name of Web App</span></h2>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button>Test1</md-button>
        <md-button>Test2</md-button>
     </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Now, my question is if anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

**EDIT:**

When I click the buttons. The color distortion goes away while the button is being clicked. When the button is not being clicked, the color distortion returns.

**EDIT:**

Important to note... That I didn't. This problem only exists for me on Chrome. On Safari, it works fine.

**EDIT:**

Here is another picture and code that may be useful in determining the problem.

```
<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools" style="background-color: green;">
        <h2 style="background-color: red"><span>Name of Web App</span></h2>
     </div>
</md-toolbar>  
<md-tabs>
    <md-tab>Hello</md-tab>
<md-tabs>
```

There is no one element that is the distorted area. The `<div>` has both the distorted color and the undistorted color.

[image]

**Final Edit:**

I have figured out the problem. It only occurs on Chrome when using tabs.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem - https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/yajbZR. What does the console show when you inspect the area with colour distortion?

Comment: Still can't replicate it with your edit - https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/yajvXG?editors=1010#0. What browser and platform are you using?

Comment: @camden_kid yeah, I am working on a CodePen to try to replicate it. I'll let you know if I can create one.

Comment: I suspect there is some CSS on that `<span flex></span>` which you may want to check.

Comment: @camden_kid no, I thought that too. But if I take out the span, the color is distorted on the right of all the elements in the same way that it is distorted in the center now.

Comment: When you remove the span and inspect the distorted area which element is it?

Comment: There is no one element that the distorted color is on. Referring to your codepen, the `div` element stretches the whole toolbar and it contains both the distorted and undistorted color. I will provide an edit shortly that shows this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125429/discussion-between-camden-kid-and-anthony-dito).

Comment: @camden_kid I created a CodePen that showcases the issue. http://cdpn.io/VKxEaZ. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't see the issue in Chrome, Firefox, Safari or Edge on a Mac or PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on a Mac with Sierra installed, it is probably a bug of Chrome running on this version of the OS.

Had a similar problem a few days back. One guy from my team would see similar artifacts when he viewed the website we developed from Chrome running on his Sierra Macbook, while the rest of us who either had not upgraded or did not use macOS did not have this issue.

For the record, I cannot replicate your issue on my Windows machine or El Capitan Macbook.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="toolbardemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content>
    <br>
    <md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools" style="background-color:green">
        <h2><span>Name of Web App</span></h2>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button>Test1</md-button>
        <md-button>Test2</md-button>
     </div>
</md-toolbar>  
  </md-content>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.toolbardemoBasicUsage md-toolbar md-icon.md-default-theme {
  color: white; }
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    });
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/rokz92/pen/qaxXBG)

Comment: I agree that your CodePen example worked, so +1. But this does not solve my problem.

Comment: If you can add CSS and JS code segment, it will be help to resolve this problem.