# Incredible Google Chrome Render

Tags: css, google-chrome

[image]
Do you see the rectangle inside the blue div? It make no sense for me that Google Chrome render this rectangle. The page is only having a div with the class "sidebar" and the css is only this:

```
.sidebar{
    background-color:#3756a0;
    width:400px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    color:#fff;
}
```

I removed all extensions in Google Chrome, I've restarted my computer. Only me experiencing this render. I'm not sure how to fix this behavior. Any help?

Edit: I'm using MacOS Sierra v 10.12 and Chrome Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit) seem to be the last update possible. The problem appear also for me here: steemconnect.com see prntscr.com/crgo04 . It seem to be not easy to reproduce.

Comment: I'm stumped-- hopefully someone can help you-- please update with a response.

Comment: Can you make a snippet that demonstrates the issue? Or if you can't, can you link to a webpage where this happens? Also, which version of Chrome, on which OS etc.

Comment: I'm using MacOS Sierra v 10.12 and Chrome Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit) seem to be the last update possible. The problem appear also for me here: https://steemconnect.com/ see http://prntscr.com/crgo04 . It seem to be not easy to reproduce.

Comment: Here is the code https://dpaste.de/Dz1S/raw

Comment: (i forgot the <!DOCTYPE html> on the paste but it doesnt matter whatever i do i still see this box)

Comment: Well, as you can guess I can't reproduce the problem. For me the rectangles simply aren't there. Neither on the screen nor in the DOM. So, sorry. But can you edit the question and put the new info in? Comments aren't really the place for that kind of info. Also, can you confirm that the problem doesn't occur on any other computer or any other browser on the same computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is going to have all shots in the dark I think but here are some things you could try:

1. Set `* { all:initial; }` to reset all style props to initial.
2. Switch display from `inline` to `inline-block` to `block` on the div / body.
3. Does the issue happen in Firefox? Safari?
4. Install [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) and see if it happens there.
5. Try going into the chrome devtools drawers and disable emulation and other options as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420516/google-chrome-dev-tools-automatically-opens-the-drawer-pane).

Comment: NP! I prefer canary for development anyways because it's got more devtools and a built-in devtools dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem a few days back. One guy from my team would see similar artifacts when he viewed the website we developed from Chrome running on his Sierra Macbook, while the rest of us who either had not upgraded or did not use macOS did not have this issue.

So, this is probably a bug of Chrome running on this version of the OS and it will get sorted eventually.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907983/angular-material-toolbar-color-distorted/40061871) question.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem. Calibration of colors in OSX helped out.

Preferences -> Monitors -> Colors